# How many ways can I show integer-linear dependence of $n$ vectors with bounded coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have $n$ vectors $(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n)$, lets say they are in $\Bbb{R}^2$ for concreteness but they could be in any vector space $V$ where $\dim V < n$.  I'm wondering if there is a combinatorics answer to how many integer combinations sum to zero given a bound on the coefficients.

$$0 = k_1 v_1 + k_2 v_2 + \cdots+ k_n v_n
\\ N\ge k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_n \\ k_i \in \Bbb{N}
$$

In other words, what is the size of the solution set of such $k_i$? My experience tells me that the intersection of combinatorics, linear algebra, and discrete math is just plain hard. But maybe someone has an idea of how to calculate this??

Comment: Other than brute force... I can do that much.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution space is the set of integer points in what's called a polytope, which is a bounded set of points in space that satisfy a set of linear equations and inequalities. You have already given the set of equations and inequalities. If you want to count the number of integer point solutions, look up the software LattE https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software.php for example that efficiently counts the number of integer points in a polytope in fixed dimension, faster than brute force, using generating rational functions to express the set of integer points.